# Android:Populating spinner according to the values entered or selected using Autocomplete text view

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to populate the spinner according to the values selected from auto-complete.When ever i select a value from the auto-complete edit text corresponding to that value there will b some data's in SQLite.It should fetch those values and display it in spinner.

Comment: use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` with setup `FilterQueryProvider`

Comment: can u give me an example or reference to understand that?

Comment: sure, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830)